# Laravel 5 database table relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am starting with learning the database table relationships in Laravel 5. As a cakePHPer something just work a little bit different. My first test is this...

Table containing different sql_types:

```
class ElementFieldType extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'sql_type'];

}
```

Table containing fields linked to the sql_types in the ElementFieldType Model (element_field_type_id is a foreign key):

```
class ElementField extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['api', 'element_field_type_id', 'label', 'type'];

    public function type() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ElementFieldType');
    }

}
```

In my controller after finding the ElementField, I want to access the sql_type using:

```
$field = ElementField::find($id);
echo $field->type->sql_type;
```

But I get below error, meaning to what I can tell, that there should be an element_field_id key in ElementFieldType, but that cannot be right.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'element_field_types.element_field_id' 
in 'where clause' (SQL: select `sql_type` from `element_field_types` 
where `element_field_types`.`element_field_id` = 1 and `element_field_types`.`element_field_id` 
is not null limit 1)
```

A database dump:

```
CREATE TABLE `element_fields` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `element_field_type_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `api` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `element_field_types` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sql_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `element_fields`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `element_fields_element_field_type_id_foreign` (`element_field_type_id`),
  ADD KEY `element_fields_element_field_type_id_index` (`element_field_type_id`);

ALTER TABLE `element_field_types`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `element_fields`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `element_fields_element_field_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`element_field_type_id`) REFERENCES `element_field_types` (`id`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do this with `belongsTo` instead of `hasOne` to get the functionality that I wanted:

```
class ElementField extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['api', 'element_field_type_id', 'element_id', 'label', 'explanation', 'type', 'mandatory'];

    public function type() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ElementFieldType', 'element_field_type_id');
    }

}
```

Now with `$field->type->sql_type` I get exactly what I want

Comment: brilliant you got to the issue yourself, always good to do that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your foreign key with relation. Try to change your relation in the model like bellow:

```
public function type() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ElementField', 'element_field_type_id');
}
```

You can read more about here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: I tried that before, but getting this error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'element_field_types.element_field_type_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `element_field_types` where `element_field_types`.`element_field_type_id` = 1 and `element_field_types`.`element_field_type_id` is not null limit 1)`

Comment: can you post your database schema?

Comment: Added it to the question. Thanx in advance

Comment: May you need to move your relation to the ElementField. Look at my answer.  Also you don't need the foreign key 'element_field_type_id ' within the protected $fillable

Comment: The thing is, the fieldtypes act like categories and the fields like products. Thus products belongs to categories and categories has many products. What you are saying is I cannot make this link to fetch category info when I am on product level? That I have to make two seperate queries to get fieldtype info?

Answer (score 0):

You query has nothing to link to with in the first table, you need a ref to `ElementField` within the `ElementFieldType`as the following has nothing to hook into.

So try and add the id field relationship to the `ElementFieldType` table:

```
  element_fields_id
```

So that when calling:

```
  public function type() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ElementFieldType');
}
```

It now has a hook to call on the `ElementFieldType` table. As what that will do is take the current table name and add id to it, so it will look for the field: `element_fields_id`

so the schema should be:

```
   CREATE TABLE `element_field_types` (
     `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     `element_fields_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `sql_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So now when calling `echo $field->type->sql_type;`it will look within the `element_field_types` table with a field called `element_field_types_id`  hopefully that makes sense,

Basically you dont need `element_field_types_id` is in the other tabel just the `element_fields_id`field in the other one instead.

Comment: The thing is, the fieldtypes act like categories and the fields like products. Thus products belongs to categories and categories has many products. What you are saying is I cannot make this link to fetch category info when I am on product level? That I have to make two seperate queries to get fieldtype info?